# change the font size or the font color for the labels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, charts, fill

I am working with angularjs google chart API. I have multiple charts in my webpage. I want to make one of the charts **h-axis labels** to hide or make the labels font color to white so that it is not shown on the webpage. I went through the API but seems there is no such configuration options working right now. 
**Generated code:**

[image]

Is there a option modifying the svg elements for that particular chart to hide the `h-axis labels`.

**js code:**

sample code tried but failed:

```
$scope.chart.options = {
    timeline: {
        showRowLabels: false,
    },
    hAxis: {title: 'Priority', titleTextStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize:'0'}},
};
```

I tried to change font size to 0 but even that didn't worked.

Comment: @WhiteHat - Any inputs on this.Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the h-axis labels?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO - Labels shown on x-axis (Jan 2018, feb, Mar ) . And i want to hide those labels only for the first chart..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the selector i was able to craft. Hope it works for you.

If not please tell me.

```
#timeline div div div svg g:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @nan Looks like it did jajaja. Happy to help